# Should I preserve pool object (and its workers) throughout the whole program in this case?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am currently modifying an existing program to contain multi-processing features so that it can be used more efficiently on multi-core systems. I am using Python3's multiprocessing module to implement this. I'm fairly new to multiprocessing and I was wondering whether my design is very efficient or not.

The general execution steps of my program is as following:

- Main process

  - call function1() -> create pool of workers and carry out certain operations in parallel. close pool.
  - call function2() -> create pool of workers and carry out certain operations in parallel. close pool.
  - call function3() -> create pool of workers and carry out certain operations in parallel. close pool.
  - and repeat until end.

Now you may ask why I would create pool of workers and close it in each function. The reason is that after completion of one function, I need to combine all the results that were processed in parallel and output some statistical values needed for the next function. So for example, function1() might get the mean which is needed by function2().

Now I realize creating a pool of workers repeatedly has its costs in Python. I was wondering if there was a way of preserving the workers between function1 and function2 because the nature of parallelization is the exact same in both functions.

One way I was thinking was creating the mp.Pool object in the main process and pass it as an argument to each function, but I'm not sure if that would be a valid way of doing so. Also, a side note is that I am also concerned about memory consumption of the program.

I am hoping if someone could validate my idea or suggest a better way of achieving the same thing.

*edit thought it would be more helpful if I included some code.

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=min(args.cpu, len(chroms)))
find_and_filter_reads_partial = partial(find_and_filter_reads, path_to_file, cutoff)
filtered_result = pool.map(find_and_filter_reads_partial, chroms)
pool.close()
```

Comment: I think the bottleneck or cost of multi-processing in Python is the serialisation of input or output. E.g. if the output of function 1 are a bunch of large objects that are using in function 2. you might as well just call function 1 and 2 in another function of map that function to pool instead.

Comment: My input and output are large numpy arrays, so what I did was save them on disk using np.save(). I'm not sure if I can do what you're suggesting because I do need to combine the outputs of function1 before running function2.